# Google rechaza app por SMS handler

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un problema con una app en play store, yo usaba los permisos SMS para autenticar por OTP ahora con las nuevas políticas de google, esta appa fue rechazada.

Entonces coloque la sugerencia de autenticar via API SMS Retriever y removí todos los permisos que pedian SMS y google sigue mandando mi APP al baul por la misma razón

¿Que puede estar faltando?

estos son mis permisos de manifest. cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: El problema no es solo por SMS si no tambien por otros mas, deberias leer la documentacion que te proporcionan, yo tengo el mismo problema. Lo que se puede hacer es llenar todo un formulario explicando el por que usas esos permisos especiales

Comment: Leí la documentación y no aparece ningun otro permiso que amerite rechazo, aparte el rechazo de la app store dice especificamente SMS handler, cuando y ano existe. El más cercano es el CALL_PHONE pero ese no está prohibido, solo el CALL_LOG

Comment: Pero si mandaré el formulario a ver que onda.

Comment: AHHH! PD: Las apk una ves subidas tienen un tiempo de revicion, si aun no paso este tiempo,deberas esperar un rato, verifica que mañana este todo en orden

Comment: @LcsGrz yo tengo el problema similar con mi App, después de la nueva reglamentación de google mi App no es aceptada en la playstore, ya envíen desde el 2018 3 veces el formulario explicando porque uso permiso de SMS y lo rechazan, mi App envía SMS a un GPS es para posicionamiento y rastreo, ya no he encontrado en ninguna parte como enviar SMS en android.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que el problema se debe a que estas definiendo el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Este permiso se usa para una implementación de [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) la cual es obsoleta y que se dejo de usar a partir del 10 de abril de 2018, es demasiado importante cambies a [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).

> **Las API de servidor y cliente de GCM están en desuso y se eliminarán**
>   **el 11 de abril de 2019.** Migre las aplicaciones de GCM a Firebase Cloud
>   Messaging (FCM).

Comment: creo que tienes razón, lo voy a cambiar, gracias.

Comment: Pues se lo quité y tampoco :( quien sabe que diablos es.